# Notification cannot be received on IOS for the first time with apnsclient for python

Tags: python, ios, notifications

I use apns-client package in python to push notification to IOS devices

```
self.con = self.session.get_connection("push_production", cert_file=PRO_PEM_FILE, passphrase=PASS_PHRASE)
self.srv = APNs(self.con)

message = Message([token], badge = badge, alert = alert)
res = self.srv.send(message)

for token, reason in res.failed.items():
   code, errmsg = reason
   print "Device failed: {0}, reason: {1}".format(token, errmsg)

for code, errmsg in res.errors:
   print "Error:", errmsg

if res.needs_retry():
   retry_message = res.retry()
```

With the code above,I can receive notification most of the time.
However,if several hours has passed since  the last notification is received,I can not receive notification without any exception at server side.
I can tell the code `self.srv.send(message)` did excute without any response,according to the apns-client document,no response means sending notification successfully.

What can I do to make sure client does receive server's notification?
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If my answer is exactly what you are looking for, please upvote and mark as answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Ricky But if my device is online,I still cannot receive my first notification,is it because the first notification has been stored?

Comment: You will only receive the notification when your app is on the background/inactive. You will not receive the notification when your app is on the foreground.

Comment: @Ricky Hmm,But I cannot receive the notification even if my app is on the background,it seems like my apns_token is invalid which is not,because I can receive the other notifications afterwards.

Comment: Do you put [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)]; on **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**?

Comment: @Ricky yes,I register all notification types like you said

Comment: Since you receive the notifications, I believe your push notification cert and etcs should be correct. Code on the XCode should be good as well. Now I suspect the problem is on the server end - Python. I never code in Python, can't help you much on that. You can check https://code.google.com/p/apns-python-wrapper/ to see if it helps you. If not, I think you might want to ask another question with clearer description with more complete sample code. Hope that someone who knows python can help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push Notification is not 100% reliable and it will not guaranteed that you will receive it 100% of the time.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

> Quality of Service
>
> Apple Push Notification service includes a default Quality of Service
>   (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function.
>
> If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline,
>   the notification is stored for a limited period of time, and delivered
>   to the device when it becomes available.
>
> Only one recent notification for a particular application is stored.
>   If multiple notifications are sent while the device is offline, each
>   new notification causes the prior notification to be discarded. This
>   behavior of keeping only the newest notification is referred to as
>   coalescing notifications.
>
> If the device remains offline for a long time, any notifications that
>   were being stored for it are discarded.

If you have any important message that you want the user to receive, I would like to suggest you to try Local Notification.